# remove line break introduced by python environment

Tags: environments, python

Suppose in my LaTeX file I need to create a python environment to execute some python code which does not create any LaTeX code. The python environment would still create a (blank) minipage which causes a vertical space. Is there a LaTeX way to compile the python environment and have the minipage removed?

For instance suppose I have this LaTeX fragment:

```
Before 
\begin{python}
f = open('abc.txt', 'w')
f.write('hello')
f.close()
\end{python}
After
```

I would like to have this in the pdf generated by pdflatex:

```
Before After
```

and the python code in the python environment executed.

Here's a min working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}

Before
\begin{python}
f = open('a.txt', 'w')
f.write("hello")
f.close()
\end{python}
After

\end{document}
```

Compile above with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex
```

Comment: do you use sth. like pythontex ( https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex ) ? If so, did you check here already for tag [pythontex] ? And if it is about pythontex, can you please add said tag to your question? Thanks // Can you please add a screenshot of the minipage-problem?

Comment: No. I use python.sty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution using the `comment` package instead of `python` that does not have the problem with extra newlines and spaces. This solution only executes the Python script, but does not include its output.

Add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{python0}{%
  \begingroup
  \def\ProcessCutFile{}%
}{%
  \immediate\write18{python comment.cut > comment.out 2> comment.err}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Then, the contents of the environment `python0` will be written to the file `comment.cut`, the file will be executed by python, with any output written to `comment.out` and any errors written to `comment.err`. Like with the `python` package, you have to use `pdflatex` with the option `--shell-escape`.

Your sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{python0}{%
  \begingroup
  \def\ProcessCutFile{}%
}{%
  \immediate\write18{python comment.cut > comment.out 2> comment.err}%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
Before
\begin{python0}
f = open('a.txt', 'w')
f.write("hello")
f.close()
\end{python0}
After
\end{document}
```

The typeset document will look like

```
Before After
```

where the space between the two words originates from the space/newline after `Before` in the source code (add `%` after Before to avoid it).

You can use this solution together with the `python` package, then you have the `python` environment for including the output of the program and the `python0` environment for not including it.

Comment: That's interesting. So specialcomment modifies an env? I'll have to try it out. I actually need both the "original" python env to work (i.e. output injected into the latex code) as well as a python env that ignores the output. Can your idea with the specialcomment be used so that (1): \begin{python}[0]...\end{python} with the "[0]" ignores output and (2): \begin{python}...\end{python} without the "[0]" is the "original" python env?

Comment: No, specialcomment defines a new environment named `python` (note that the second solution does not load the `python` package, so the `python` environment is initially undefined). The main purpose of the `comment` package is to write the contents of an environment verbatim to a file. Adding an optional parameter is non-trivial, as the comment-environments are rather special. However, you could rename the environment, say to `python0`, and then use it alongside your original `python` environment. I'll add a note to my solution.

Comment: Got it. Upvote and accept as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minipage involved. What you see is an effect of the `\input` command that `python.sty` uses to include the output of the Python program. Try

```
Before\input{EmptyFile.txt}After
```

and you will note that `Before` and `After` end up on different lines.

One solution is to modify your python program to write a file with the command `\unskip`, instead of an empty one.

```python
f = open('a.txt', 'w')
f.write("hello")
f.close()
print('\unskip')# <<<< Removes the newline between Before and After
```

This will result in the LaTeX output

```
Before    After
```

The two words are separated by four spaces. Two of them originate from your document; you can remove them by adding comment signs. The other two are spurious spaces from the style file `python.sty`. Unless you want to create a personal copy of this file (see below) you can remove these spaces by adding two `\unskip` commands after the `python` environment. Here is the modified LaTeX source.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}
Before% <<<< Removes a space
\begin{python}
f = open('a.txt', 'w')
f.write("hello")
f.close()
print('\unskip')# <<<< Removes the newline between Before and After
\end{python}% <<<< Removes a space
\unskip\unskip% <<<< Removes two spaces introduced by the way python.sty defines the python environment
After
\end{document}
```

*Modifying `python.sty`:* This is not really recommended, since your copy of `python.sty` will be frozen and will not benefit from future updates of this package. Anyway, if for some reason, you can't add the extra `\unskip\unskip` line, copy `python.sty` into the directory containing your document. Under Unix or GNU/Linux, the following command copies the style file to the current working directory.

```
cp `kpsewhich python.sty` .
```

Open the local copy of `python.sty` with any text editor and add two `%` signs.

- Replace the line

  ```
  \gdef\@pythoninclude{#1}
  ```

  by

  ```
  \gdef\@pythoninclude{#1}%
  ```
- Replace the line

  ```
  \immediate\write18{cat \@pythoninclude\space\jobname.py | python > \jobname.py.out 2> \jobname.py.err}
  ```

  by

  ```
  \immediate\write18{cat \@pythoninclude\space\jobname.py | python > \jobname.py.out 2> \jobname.py.err}%
  ```

Comment: You are right. My mistake: the python env does not return a minipage. Actually I wrapping the output of the python environment inside a minipage using atbeginafter about 10+ years ago and have totally forgotten about it, until last night when I look at my own latex preamble. Yes I agree it's a bad idea to change python.sty. I'm actually thinking more along the idea of an environment that will analyze a python environment. For now, I will use your print unskip idea until I have a better solution. I guess I can have an environment called unskip that inserts the print unskip. Will upvote. Thanks.